# Feed mapping problem

Tags: nodes, commerce, feeds, importing-exporting

I want to create the following mapping for a product node: This is extracted and amended from an existing feed.

```
    'mappings' => array(
    0 => array(
      'source' => 'SKU',
      'target' => 'guid',
      'unique' => 1,
      'language' => 'und',
    ),
    1 => array(
      'source' => 'SKU',
      'target' => 'field_product:sku',
      'unique' => FALSE,
      'language' => 'und',
    ),
    2 => array(
      'source' => 'title',
      'target' => 'title',
      'unique' => FALSE,
      'language' => 'und',
    ),
    3 => array(
      'source' => 'body',
      'target' => 'body',
      'unique' => FALSE,
      'language' => 'und',
    ),
    4 => array(
      'source' => 'Group',
      'target' => 'field_product_category',
      'unique' => FALSE,
      'language' => 'und',
    ),
    5 => array(
      'source' => 'length',
      'target' => 'field_dimensions_length',
      'unique' => FALSE,
      'language' => 'und',
    ),
    6 => array(
      'source' => 'width',
      'target' => 'field_dimensions_width',
      'unique' => FALSE,
      'language' => 'und',
    ),
    7 => array(
      'source' => 'height',
      'target' => 'field_dimensions_height',
      'unique' => FALSE,
      'language' => 'und',
    ),
    8 => array(
      'source' => 'unit1',
      'target' => 'field_dimensions_unit',
      'unique' => FALSE,
      'language' => 'und',
    ),
    9 => array(
      'source' => 'weight',
      'target' => 'field_weight_weight',
      'unique' => FALSE,
      'language' => 'und',
    ),
    10 => array(
      'source' => 'unit2',
      'target' => 'field_weight_unit',
      'unique' => FALSE,
      'language' => 'und',
    ),
```

The first five items are OK and will map via nodes, the others, from 5 to 10 will not.
When I go to /Admin/Content/Settings/Content types/Product display/Manage Fields The field_weight element and field_dimensions elements are clearly shown.
How can I amend the node mapping to take these fields into consideration.?

Comment: Is there any error message showed up after you import? Also, make sure source name is matched.

Comment: Hello  jmu 20 There are no error messages because I can't find the fields I need to map to.  A direct upload through the server doesn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your code, I believe you are working on eCommerce website.

I think you need to change your **target value** to:

> 'field_dimensions:length', 'field_dimensions:width', 'field_dimensions:height', 'field_dimensions:unit','field_weight:weight','field_weight:unit'